# 94 rep for 100 rep increase

Tags: support, reputation, achievements-dialog

[image]

When I joined Programmers SE, I earned 100 points reputation bonus. However, the icon still shows that I only gained +94. Even considering last week's activity, this count is unexplainable. Did I find a bug? It's happened to me a lot, but I finally decided to report it.

Comment: Psychic guess: either unread things further down the list, or stuff you downvoted being undeleted (which isn't on the list), or things you gained rep from being deleted (similarly not listed), or a combination of the above, added up to enough points lost to total +94

Comment: It's not a bug; they're measuring different things.  One includes additional actions such as post deletions, downvotes, votes revered from fraud, etc., while the other doesn't necessarily show all of those things, by design.

Comment: @BillyMailman Is +94 for this day, or this week, etc.?

Comment: @SimonKuang It's since you last looked at that view.

Comment: Specifically, it's the difference between your current rep, totalled across all SE sites, and the same total taken the last time you opened the list. Except that it won't go up by one for creating a new account, just the +100 for assoc. Bonus, if applicable. Anything that changes rep, changes the number, even if it's not in the list.